# annoying N+1 problem when calling criteria.List()

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

see detailed description of my N+1 queries when performing a criteria.list with a join to another joined entity.
I'm quite clueless by now, perhaps someone will have an idea.

these are the objects: (properly renamed :) )
Order -> Pot <-> Cover

order is many-to-one associated to Pot. (so different orders can point to the same Pot).
Order table has a "PotId" field (with keys from Pot table).

Pot is one-to-one, bidirectionaly associated to Cover - one side is "one-to-one", the other is "many-to-one".
Cover table has a "PotId" field (with keys from Pot table).

The troubles begin when I perform:
session.CreateCriteria(typeof (Order)).CreateAlias("pot", "pot", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin).List();

what I get is a single query fetching orders+pots, and then N queries fetching cover (by cover.PotId).
tried tweaking this way and the other but to no avail.
I thought this may be linked to the issue of "no lazy loading for one-to-one associations",
but I can't get around it.
any ideas? will be happy to supply more information.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a second alias/join specified between pot and cover (or to eager load the pot -> cover relationship in your mappings).

There's also a .SetFetchMode on ICriteria that you might find interesting.

Comment: I considered fetching the appropriate covers in advance, but the query is dynamically generated and that makes it more difficult. I also thought about eager loading the pot->cover relationship, but in the real life example Order also points to Pot (many to one), and I have two joins on the same table - and still I'm seeing some entities loaded after the this query (very strange, not sure why). I've used SetFetchMode as well (and another CreateCriteria), but I see more or less the same results...

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your `batch-size` on the `Cover` entity to something > 1.  When it goes to get the first `Cover`, it should load any other ones that are referenced by existing `Pot` entities, up to the limit of `batch-size`.

Comment: I may try that, but I prefer a solution which is O(1) DB roundtrips and O(1) queries.